# Why can't we just have $\xi = 0$ as the optimal value?

Tags: proof-explanation, machine-learning

From Understanding Machine Learning:

In the proof below, why does the choice of $\xi$ being $0$ or $1-(y_1\langle w,x_i\rangle + b )$ matter?  Why can't we just have $\xi = 0$ as the optimal value as $(15.4)$ would reduce to the norm term?

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(y_1\langle w,x_i\rangle + b ) < 1$
and $\xi_i = 0,$ then $1 - \xi_i = 1$ and therefore
$(y_1\langle w,x_i\rangle + b ) < 1 - \xi_i.$

That would contradict the requirement that
$(y_1\langle w,x_i\rangle + b ) \geq 1 - \xi_i.$

In the case where $(y_1\langle w,x_i\rangle + b ) < 1,$
what is the *least* value of $\xi_i$ for which
$(y_1\langle w,x_i\rangle + b ) \geq 1 - \xi_i$?

If we add $(y_1\langle w,x_i\rangle + b ) - \xi_i$ to both sides of the inequality
$$(y_1\langle w,x_i\rangle + b ) \geq 1 - \xi_i,$$
we get the equivalent inequality
$$ \xi_i \geq 1 - (y_1\langle w,x_i\rangle + b ).$$
The least value of $\xi_i$ for which this inequality is true is when the two sides are equal,
$$ \xi_i = 1 - (y_1\langle w,x_i\rangle + b ).$$